keepassxc - enlarge font size
I am using keepassxc on ubuntu. The font size is very small, very difficult to read for me. Please let me know how to scale up the fonts. Thank you

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Dear David, thank you for your quick reply. I use 22.04.4 LTS. The text ist too small, I can not read it. So I am unable to use keepassxc. Please tell me what I can do to get a larger text. Best regards, Konrad

Per https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/621, there are several possible solutions. You may launch KeePassXC from command line with "QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2 keepassxc" (or another number depending on how big the font should be). You may also install qt5ct and set the fonts via its interface. How did you install KeePassXC? The solution will change depending on the package...

Edit file /etc/environment and add a line for the scale factor (1.5 is 150%, 2 is 200%):
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5

Log out and log back in, done. From now on KeePassXC and other QT5/QT6-based program interfaces will be scaled up.

xrandr
Using xrandr to override DPI (Dots Per Inch) is a technique I've been using for years.
To launch kid3; media file metadata tagger:
xrandr --dpi 128
kid3

To launch sqlitebrowser; sqlite3 database browser:
xrandr --dpi 128
sqlitebrowser

If all else fails, this method works well on GUI apps where the fonts are too small and the GUI app doesn't allow you to pick font size.
